# Using LINQ Contains - How to make sure a specific character does not follow

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have the following linq:

```
var s = string.Join(",", products.Where(p => p.Query.Contains(tableName))
                                 .Select(p => p.ProductId.ToString()));
```

I am searching through a list but I want to omit the items where the table name is not the exact table.  To be exact, there are some tables that have an extra digit at the end and want to omit those.

For example if I search a string for table1, it should not include table10

The following would be included in the Query data above:

**INCLUDE:**

```
this is a test table1 found
This is another test table1(some other data here)
thistable1shouldbeincluded
```

**DO NOT INCLUDE**

```
this is a text table10 found
table10is here
testing this should not be included table18(testing)
```

Basically the check would be to make sure that a digit 0-9 does not follow the search criteria in the contains statement.  Anything else can follow.  I would like to keep it part of the same linq and as simple if that is possible.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: And when your `table` does not end with a digit, like `table`, do you want to return the enty like `table1here`? It is not clear what the word boundaries are here.

Comment: you probably want to use regex to do this

Comment: @Rango -- good point!

Comment: Wiktor, thank you for your input. The below answer by Matt works correctly whether the table name ends or does not end with a digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Regex: `table1(?!\d)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2D51v2/1)

```
var s = string.Join(",", products.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p.Query, $@"{tableName}(?!\d)"))
                                 .Select(p => p.ProductId.ToString()));
```